# Could we delete old database and grid version?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, rac, oracle-grid-control

We upgraded rac system and I want to ask, could I delete old grid and database version?

```
[oracle@orcl1 app]$ cd

11.2.0.3/     12.1.0.2/     Middleware/   oraInventory/

11.2.0.4/     grid/         oracle/       swlib/
```

I want to ask  can I delete manually "rm command line command"11.2.0.3/ and 11.2.0.4  grid files...  oracle/product/11.2.0.3 database ...

That's my inventory.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes" ?>

<!-- Copyright (c) 1999, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

All rights reserved. -->

<!-- Do not modify the contents of this file by hand. -->

<INVENTORY>

<VERSION_INFO>

   <SAVED_WITH>12.1.0.2.0</SAVED_WITH>

   <MINIMUM_VER>2.1.0.6.0</MINIMUM_VER>

</VERSION_INFO>

<HOME_LIST>

<HOME NAME="OraDb11203_home1" LOC="/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.3/dbhome_1" TYPE="O" IDX="2">

   <NODE_LIST>

      <NODE NAME="orcl1"/>

      <NODE NAME="orcl2"/>

   </NODE_LIST>

</HOME>

<HOME NAME="OraDb12102_home1" LOC="/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/dbhome_1" TYPE="O" IDX="5">

   <NODE_LIST>

      <NODE NAME="orcl1"/>

      <NODE NAME="orcl2"/>

   </NODE_LIST>

</HOME>

<HOME NAME="OraGrid12102" LOC="/u01/app/12.1.0.2/grid" TYPE="O" IDX="4" CRS="true"/>

<HOME NAME="OraGrid11gR3" LOC="/u01/app/11.2.0.3/grid" TYPE="O" IDX="1" REMOVED="T"/>

<HOME NAME="OraGrid11gR204" LOC="/u01/app/11.2.0.4/grid" TYPE="O" IDX="3" REMOVED="T"/>

</HOME_LIST>

<COMPOSITEHOME_LIST>

</COMPOSITEHOME_LIST>

</INVENTORY>
```

---

EDIT:  I started deinstall tool in 11.2.0.3 .. I don'T want to delete grid 12.1.0.2 but I think it can delete 12.1.0.2's grid. right?

```
######################### CHECK OPERATION START #########################
## [START] Install check configuration ##


Checking for existence of the Oracle home location /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.3/dbhome_1
Oracle Home type selected for deinstall is: Oracle Real Application Cluster Database
Oracle Base selected for deinstall is: /u01/app/oracle
Checking for existence of central inventory location /u01/app/oraInventory
Checking for existence of the Oracle Grid Infrastructure home /u01/app/12.1.0.2/grid
The following nodes are part of this cluster: orcl1,orcl2
Checking for sufficient temp space availability on node(s) : 'orcl1,orcl2'

## [END] Install check configuration ##


Network Configuration check config START

Network de-configuration trace file location: /u01/app/oraInventory/logs/netdc_check2015-11-02_08-53-27-AM.log

Network Configuration check config END

Database Check Configuration START

Database de-configuration trace file location: /u01/app/oraInventory/logs/databasedc_check2015-11-02_08-53-29-AM.log

Use comma as separator when specifying list of values as input

Specify the list of database names that are configured in this Oracle home []:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle provides a deinstallation tool starting with Oracle 11.

It's located in *$ORACLE_HOME/deinstall/*  (in your case the *old* Homes). It takes care of the inventory and remote hosts in case of a RAC.

Comment: can you look my question? I edited..

Comment: Which Grid do you mean? You don't want to deinstall the 12.1.0.2 Grid Infrastructure. If you have older 12.1.0.1 or 11.2.0.4 Grid Infrastatructures, they have a deinstall script of their own. Generally the deinstall script only delete the versions you run it from.

Comment: I want to delete 11.2.0.3  Grid Infrastructures

Comment: run the deinstall script from the 11.2.0.3 grid home. I can't remember but for 11.2.0.3 it is possible that you need to download the deinstall tool from OTN, check for "Oracle De-install Utility" on the download section. Be sure to check the documentation, especially the "Installing and Upgrading" section of the "Grid Infrastructure Installation Guide" for your environment.